# blank gravity form entries with API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-apps-script, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm trying to create an entry in a Gravity form via API post in Google Apps script.

An entry gets created but the values are showing blank. any insight of where I'm possibly going wrong would be appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
function gravityForms(){

const url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/18/entries';

const payload = [{"2":"My name"}];

const options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload),
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true
  };
  
    options.headers = {    
    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("ck_xxxxxxxxxxxx:cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
  };

const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

console.log(res.getContentText());

}
```

This is the response I get back in the logger

```
{"0":{"2":"My name"},"form_id":18,"id":3320}
```

Comment: Can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike here it is https://docs.gravityforms.com/web-api/#post-entries

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `[]` from the entry object and it worked. funny since the examples show to add them.